# How to detect a players name in minecraft without testfor command in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know that you can use `testfor @p`, but imagine the adventure maps or story maps if you care about chats. You will see it knows your name; for example, if the player name is "345tyou", we can have a simulated conversation where the player name is substituted in:

> (DAD):345tyou u have to buy cookies
> (345tyou) okay dad

The map should be able to detect the player's username and substitute it in where required: like flowerpot22

> (DAD):flowerpot22 u have to buy cookies
> (Flowerpot22)okay dad

I think it has some thing to do with command blocks.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: The java edition

Comment: Okay, which version of Java Edition? If it's 1.13 or higher your `/testfor` won't work, it's removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try [generating](https://minecraft.tools/en/json_text.php) a [Json String](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raw_JSON_text_format#Entity_Names).

The `selector` allows you to dynamically substitute an entity's name in your text, with the argument being a selector string. For example:

```
..., {"selector": "@p"}, ...
```

Will print the closest player.

---

Note that `@p` will select the closest player to the command's source (command block, likely).
To select the player it is displayed to, use `@s` for 'self'.